# How to reverse engineer a proprietary FSK protocol

Tags: software-defined-radio, modes

Assuming I wanted to reverse engineer 13FSK, what steps would I take to begin reverse engineering it? I have seen tools such as inspectrum and baudline that can help me view the raw signals, but I am unsure as to how to reverse engineer the 13FSK and then build a way to receive and transmit data using 13FSK.

Comment: FYI, unless the name is being misused "13FSK" just means that it's frequency-shift modulation with 13 distinct frequencies. What you need to know after that is the _coding_, the meaning of those 13 symbols.

Comment: Correct. Do you have any ideas on how to figure out the actual data?

Comment: You'll probably need more to go on, like having some message with some idea of what it should contain.

Comment: I agree - first you will want some information about who is transmitting it, and that may give clues as to the content.  There is not enough information in this question to give a definitive answer.

Comment: I would suggest you look at Oona Räisänen's blog for inspiration at least. http://www.windytan.com/

Comment: Welcome to Amateur Radio.  Please take a moment for the tour at https://ham.stackexchange.com/Tour   Note that since this database will be around for years we generally don't assume that raw links will hold their value - so please edit this and provide a rough explanation of what people might find if they follow this link.  If you do so you are more likely to turn around the voting on this one.

Comment: @SDsolar I have converted kc3wd's answer to a comment. And I appreciate it when you post friendly and helpful comments to newcomers. :-)

Comment: I would start with looking into URH (https://github.com/jopohl/urh). It will automatically try and demodulate and decode your FSK signals. And if you are lucky you can see repeating data and glean something from it.

Answer (score 1):

To reverse engineer anything, you need a sample to look at. Can you generate valid 13FSK signals?  If so, then you need to capture it.

Also, you'll need manipulate the transmitted payload so you can compare "before and after" to see what changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you are looking at something like Pactor 3 or 4 ... then good luck.

I did have a look at this a few years ago after buying a very expensive (but functional) Pactor 3 Modem....

I apologize that this is not a more constructive comment. However such Digital transmissions are usually compressed (possibly using commercial
algorithms) and may additionally use proprietary codecs.